# matplotlib: How to plot multiple scatter plots in one grid where each plot is different color based on a separate list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am currently plotting the color values of images per pixel, I am trying to create a plot for each image. I have around 100 images. I want all plots to be present in a single grid but I still want to track what image the plot represents.

For the "third variable" of the color of the image, it will depend on a separate list valued 0-100 and each plot has a corresponding level.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here is the relevant snippet that gets looped for each image. `z` is the list containing the numbers 0-100 (eg z=[5,2,6,13,100,0...])

```
    x = h_values[count]
    y = v_values[count]

    w = plt.cm.seismic(z[count]/100)

    ax.set_xlabel("H",fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel("V",fontsize=12)
    ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')
    ax.scatter(x, y, color=w, s=1, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, edgecolors='None', vmin=0, vmax=100)
```

Comment: Added the snippet in my post :)

Comment: and what is the question now?

Comment: I want each plot (h_values[count] vs v_values[count]) to have a different color based on the value of z[count], with that snippet everything is just the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimum working example of what you might be trying to do:

```py
import pylab as pl

pl.clf()
for count in range(5):
    pl.scatter(pl.rand(10), pl.rand(10), color=pl.cm.seismic(count / 5.0), s=50)
```

Result:
[image: result]

I guess your `z` is an integer, so after division by 100 you always get 0. Am I right? I'm avoiding integer division using `5.0` instead of `5`.